# Python script for creating JSONL training files for AutoML Natural Language

Tags: python, google-cloud-automl, automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

i am trying to create the JSONL training files for AutoML Natural Language and it say in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare#expandable-2)

> To help you create JSONL training files, AutoML Natural Language
> offers a Python [script](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/scripts/input_helper_v2.py) that converts plain text files into
> appropriately formatted JSONL files. See the comments in the script
> for details.

i tried to follow the comments but i didn't get them
i tried runing it with this

```
python jason.py C:\..dic.csv C:\..text.txt gs://mybucket
```

but it gives me :

```
(with 5 blank lines skipped)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jason.py", line 688, in <module>
    main()
  File "jason.py", line 680, in main
    UploadFiles(annotated_files, FLAGS.target_gcs_directory)
  File "jason.py", line 636, in UploadFiles
    f.write(csv_line)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

can anyone help me with an example of how to run the [script](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/scripts/input_helper_v2.py) please

Comment: `csv_line` is of type bytes because of  the call to .encode in this line: `csv_line = (converted_file.ml_use + ',' + dst_path + '\n').encode('utf8')` but you've opened your file in text mode with this line: `with open(csv_file_path, 'w') as f:`. Quick fix would be to change the mode to 'wb'. Better fix would be to open the file with encoding='...' and use a CSV writer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [tool](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/scripts/input_helper_v2.py) provided in created using python2. You can run `python2 jsonl_converter.py -s sample_1.txt gs://your-bucket` so that you won't be editing the code provided. Or if you'd like you can follow @Justin Ezequiel suggestion if you need to run it in python3. I just used the -s option to auto split long files.

Test using python 2:
[image]

JSONL in designated GCS bucket:
[image]